# how to use ajax search lite wordpress plugin shortcode in a custom html page?

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

my custom HTML page located in /wp-content Folder . and i already tried by changing the extension to `.php` and calling 
wpload

```
<?php require( '../wp-load.php' ); ?>
```

and adding the shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wpdreams_ajaxsearchlite]'); ?>
```

into body tag . i can't say this doesn't work . **this is working but not rendering the search bar properly** *For Reference You can Check This*

1. **--the page after doing above experiment---   [Link](http://movieeater.com/wp-content/420.php)**
2. **--the Normal html page (or page before doing above experiment)---   [Link](http://movieeater.com/420.html)**

and if you wanna see how proper ajax-lite-search bar look like check the red colour search bar on this page- MovieEater.com

Comment: can you try with page template ?

Comment: Lil bit explain How ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ refer link.